# Custom post type menu

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, posts

The theme I have has its own admin menu using `add_menu_page` and `add_submenu_page`.

**Question:** is there any way for me to add custom post types to this admin menu? Instead of the custom post type appearing in its own menu?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to WordPress Answers, glad to have you here. I think this is what you are looking for?

- [**Custom Post Type Menus**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8483/custom-post-type-menus)

P.S. BTW, in the future you may want to search the site first before asking. The above almost identical question was asked yesterday.