# Menu Error in Admin Console with Custom Plugin: You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page

Tags: plugin-development, admin-menu

*(**Moderator's note:** Original title was "Getting error: You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page. Trying to build custom plugin")*

I'm trying to write my own custom WordPress plugin, but as soon as I click on the menu I get the following error:

> *You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.*

My plugin is located under:

```
/wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce-group-pricing/wp-e-commerce-group-pricing.php
```

The code is below, I'm new to WordPress, so maybe I'm doing something wrong:

```
if ( is_admin() ) {
  // Hooks and admin menu setup
  add_action('admin_menu', 'add_options_gp');

  function add_options_gp() {
    add_submenu_page('wpsc-sales-logs','WPEC - Group Pricing','Group Pricing',7,
                     'wp-e-commerce-group-pricing', 'price_options');
  }

  function price_options(){
    // Page content goes here...
  }
}
```

Comment: You are showing an `add_submenu_page()` but where is your `add_menu_page()` for `'wpsc-sales-logs'`?

Comment: Try changing the 7 for "manage_options".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue may be in your call to `add_submenu_page()`:

```
add_submenu_page('wpsc-sales-logs',...
```

The first parameter needs to be a reference to your Menu Page's "slug", i.e. if you use `'edit.php'` instead you'll see that you get a menu option under the *"Posts"* menu page:

```
add_submenu_page('edit.php','WPEC - Group Pricing','Group Pricing', 7,
                 'wp-e-commerce-group-pricing', 'price_options');
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: WordPress Admin Menu with Submenu Page URL]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/Fullscreen-20110208-080436.png))</sub>

So you need to find out what URL fragment (the part past `http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/`) that your menu page uses.

#### UPDATE

For future readers, Roland's issue was **a hook priority** issue. Changing priority from 10 to 11 fixed it in his case:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_options_gp',11);
```

P.S. You really don't need the `if` statement testing for `is_admin()` since you are using the `'admin_menu'` hook; it only fires in the admin.

Comment: @Mike - It's definitely that, I need to find out what the slug is for WP-E-Commerce plugin, I thought its wpsc-sales-logs , but not to sure, it there a way to get this

Comment: @Roland - Hover your mouse over the menu section and look at your status bar. You need everything after `http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/`.

Comment: The parent looks like this http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpsc-sales-logs, if I use wpsc-sales-logs as the slug it shows under the menu, but then I get my error

Comment: @Roland - Try `'admin.php?page=wpsc-sales-logs'` instead of `'wpsc-sales-logs'`.

Comment: @mike-I did this add_submenu_page('admin.php?page=wpsc-sales-logs','WPEC - Group Pricing','Group Pricing', 7, 'wp-e-commerce-group-pricing', 'price_group_options'); and now it's not shpwing up at all.

Comment: @Roland - Forgive me. I made a wrong assumption *(frankly the admin menu system is a real PITA, see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7029/)*; try `add_submenu_page('wpsc-sales-logs','WPEC - Group Pricing','Group Pricing', 'manage_options', 'wp-e-commerce-group-pricing', 'price_options')` and see if that works.

Comment: @Mike - Thanx for the help, but this still not working, really do not know what the problem is.

Comment: @Roland - When you say *"still not working"* are you saying that you are still getting the *"You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page"* message, or is it another problem? If the same, are you logged in with an administrator login?  I downloaded WP e-Commerce and tested the above and it works when I'm logged in as an administrator role.

Comment: @Roland - Something else to try; set the priority higher so your code runs after theirs: `add_action('admin_menu', 'add_options_gp',11);`  *(Not sure if this will help, but it might...)*

Comment: @Mike - Awesome, the problem was the priority. :-) after I've added in add_action('admin_menu', 'add_options_gp',11); the "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page" error disappeared. Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it!!!!

Comment: @Roland - Yep, it's always something! :)  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Does it show up and work if you add it as sub menu page to some other menu item? Please try this to make shure it works and the only problem is the slug. Some point i'd suggest to look is the parent plugin folder and a search for add_menu_page in there.

If you look into your wp ecommerce folder: wp-e-commerce > wpsc-admin > admin.php on line 71-96 you'll find the way how it's done in the plugin.

@Mike: [Here's the download link](http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wp-e-commerce.zip)

try to use `add_object_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $access_level, $file, $function = '', $icon_url = '');` with `'admin.php?page=wpsc-sales-logs'` or `'wpsc-sales-logs'`.

Or try to use something like `add_submenu_page('wpsc-sales-logs', __('WPEC - Group Pricing', 'wpsc'), __('Group Pricing', 'wpsc'), 7, 'wpsc-sales-logs', 'price_options');` or take a look at the reference from wp-e-commerce plugin files at (file from above) line 99-108

Comment: Yes it works on other menu items.

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: Good research.  His non-working example mirrors what's it in the plugin's code, so maybe it is a hook priority thing?

Comment: I've tried this- add_object_page( 'WPEC - Group Pricing', 'WPEC - Group Pricing', 7, 'wp-e-commerce-group-pricing', 'price_group_options', $icon_url = ''); Menu appears above the Store menu, and works, tried add_submenu_page('wpsc-sales-logs', __('WPEC - Group Pricing', 'wpsc'), __('Group Pricing', 'wpsc'), 7, 'wpsc-sales-logs', 'price_options'); and nope not working if I put in my parameters

Comment: could you post a screenshot somewhere so i can see where exactly which is appearing? Maybe you could solve this with the menu order number.