# Why does hook priority affects admin menu permission error?

Tags: hooks, admin-menu

On [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/8863/4741), there was this final comment

> For future readers, Roland's issue was a hook priority issue. Changing priority from 10 to 11 fixed it in his case

The answer seems already closed, so I couldn't comment, but why/how would a hook priority make an admin menu work or produce a permission error?

> You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

Comment: That you can't comment seems to be a Q of "how many rep points are needed?".

Comment: I am generally able to comment. I think the question was simply closed or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Priority

*All* hooks & filters have a priority. Those are used to *order* the functions that are attached to hooks. By default the priority is `10`.

As the default is 10, there's a big chance that your filter/action gets hooked too early and therefore can't affect the actual output.

**Edit:**

1. Imagine that the plugin hooks it's bootstrap into the `'admin_init'` hook to add *something* that needs permissions to access. Inside that bootstrap it hooks something to the (fictional) `'fantastic_hook'`.
2. Imagine that you hook some extension of a plugin to the `'after_theme_setup'` hook. There you add some function to the (fictional) `'fantastic_hook'` too.

So the result of `print_r( $GLOBALS['wp_filter']['fantastic_hook'] );` would be the following:

```
[10] Array => ['fantastic_hook']
    ( 
        Array => ['your_custom_extension']
        Array => ['the_plugin_bootstrap']
    )
```

As your extension **and** the bootstrap run both at priority `10`. But yours got added first and will therefore run first. And there comes the problem...

### About the menu items

The admin menu works pretty similar: You have a priority (the (sub-)array index) that cares about ordering and placing the menu items.

```
// Example for your functions.php:
function dump_filters()
{
    $output = '';
    foreach ( array( $GLOBALS['menu'], $GLOBALS['submenu'] ) as $item )
        $output .= var_export( $item, false );
    echo "<pre>{$output}</pre>";
}
add_action( 'adminmenu', 'dump_filters', 999 );
```

---

Note: I wrote a pretty intense [post](http://unserkaiser.com/code/wordpress-admin-menu-in-detail/) about the menu order, where you can see how you'd [reorder](http://unserkaiser.com/code/wordpress-admin-menu-in-detail/3/) the menu and read a little bit about the behind-the-scenes of the menu and it's limitations.

Comment: "As the default is 10, there's a big chance that your filter/action gets hooked too early and therefore can't affect the actual output." - Why? or what's 'too early'? I see that in some plugins it appears to work just fine without explicitly setting the priority to higher. Also, the menu option does show, but it generates this weird and seemingly unrelated permission error... Otherwise, thanks for the link. I'll check it out.

Comment: Yes, you're able to _add whatever stuff_. Point is that other code runs later and (for example) permissions are set when the later code is run. So if you add yours earlier, then the permissions aren't in place and therefore fail. Second: If 2 functions hook into priority 10 at different times (they can't run simultaneously), then the one that gets triggered first, gets added first and therefore runs first. This is where the error comes from. So in case you aren't sure: Run your function later.

Comment: Ok... I understand the solution, it evidently works. I'm not that sure I'm clear about the reason why it doesn't work without changing the priority, or why it produces a permission error where permissions/capabilities are set correctly on both places. I guess it's just one of many WP quirks.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to make it clear again and update the answer slightly.

Comment: Explanation better now?

Comment: Thanks @kaiser. I'd have to look at my code again in this context to see what might have caused a conflict if it was executed first. It still 'feels' strange to me that Wordpress spits out this permission error message that doesn't quite seem related (or help in any way figure out that the root cause is wrong priority order)

Comment: WordPress isn't known for beeing _Debug Heaven_ ;)