# Is there a neater way to do this?

Tags: plugins

So, on most of my sites I tend to create one admin user for myself, and one or more other users for the client. Inevitably I always want to simplify the interface for the client user/s, and I've found myself using a number of clients to achieve this. I'm wondering whether there is a cleaner, faster and maybe easily reusable way to do this, instead of going through the same process of installing plugins and configuring them each time.

The most common plugin mix I use is:
Adminimize (to remove meta boxes and fine tune some admin elements like disabling screen options)
Admin Menu Editor (to hide menu items and create new items)
Hide Admin Panels (to hide menu items per user or role)

Instead of Hide Admin Panels I can also use Members which gives me the same result, although it is a different plugin altogether.

So, the question is whether I could simplify things a bit ahd still have the same kind of control over what different users see in WP-Admin.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A "neater" way would be to create your own custom plug-in that bundles all of these features together.  You could hard-code your initial configuration, then just drop it in whenever you create a new site.

Answer (score 1):

See [this thread from Mike](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7029/the-great-wordpress-admin-menu-challenge-of-jan-2011-a-k-a-how-to-resolve-some) and the according [trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16048). I would suggest to just use Mikes Class instead of various Plugins. Franks Plugin Adminimize is great, but has the drawback that it uses css to set items to `display: none;`. Mikes Class completely unsets the items.

Answer (score 0):

A clean way to do this is by making clever use of your functions.php file. [Check this article on catswhocode.com](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-wordpress-dashboard-hacks). I think especially the last tip in this article is what you are looking for.